# Is it possible to make "???" a keyword that can be highlighted?

Tags: highlight, syntax, keyword

Is it possible to make `???` (3 question marks) a keyword, and highlight it?

I have tried the following in a syntax file. Other strings on the line are highlighted, but not `???`. `\?\?\?` does not work either.

```
syntax keyword textTodos TODO ??? XXX LLL
highlight default link textTodos Todo
```

Comment: Use a `:syn match` for the `???` entry instead, that should be the easiest solution.

Comment: yeah also easier would be to use the `matchadd()` and alike functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to do it with a `syntax  match` like this:

```
syntax match TQM '???' containedin=ALL
highlight link TQM Todo
```

If you want to have it always available, you could put the following in your `vimrc`:

```
augroup my_syntax_autocmd
    autocmd!
    autocmd Syntax * syntax match TQM '???' containedin=ALL |  highlight link TQM Todo
augroup END
```

Answer (score 4):

syntax keywords are supposed to be - well - keywords. Initially, this meant, it must match the definition of the ['iskeyword' option](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#'iskeyword'), which usually does not include the quotation mark. Some years later, the iskeyword option has been de-coupled from the syntax highlighting option and now one can use the `:syn iskeyword` command to specify the iskeyword option only for syntax highlighting (which falls back to the `iskeyword`) option, if it is not specified.

To make this possible, you can add the `?` to the syntax definition of a keyword by using `:syn iskeyword=<c-r>=&iskeyword<cr>,?`

This uses the [expression-register =](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-R_=) to get the current value of the `iskeyword` option and adds the `?` to it.

Note however, this can have unwanted consequences to your syntax highlighting, depending on the patterns used in the syntax definitions.